# How to get the default colors on Android

Tags: android

I have a custom component that I want to give the same colors as a TextView.
That is, I don't want to copy its colors, I want to get the default background and foreground colors, if there's such a concept on android.

[Edit]

The following seems to yield the text color of my TextView. But is it just luck? It's not intuitive to me that a default TextView would use `android.R.attr.textColorSecondary`? And why does not `resolveAttribute` return the color directly?

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorSecondary, tv, true);
Color holyColor = getResources().getColor(tv.resourceId);
```

[Edit]

I found the source code of TextView at [android.git.kernel.org](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;hb=HEAD), but it seemed to contain a lot of referrences to `com.android.internal.R`, which I don't think I should use in my own code. I'm currently looking for some kind of evidence that `TextView` uses `android.R.attr.textColorSecondary`.

[Edit]

I found some kind of evidence at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles), in [styles.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD) that `TextView` uses `android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall`. `textAppearanceSmall` is documented to default to "secondary text color".

I guess I was lucky after all, but I still don't like that little code snippet of mine.

Comment: Your observation is also backed by the documentation here:
[http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes "Referencing style attributes")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are attributes.  Attributes link widgets to styles.  For example, `android:background` is what you'd set for a particular view, but there's attributes like `android:panelBackground` and `android:windowBackground` that you can use override to affect the system as a whole.

You should look through [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) and then link to those attributes in your widget.  There should be a number of them that are linked to TextView; it would make sense to download the Android source code and see which attributes are used.